# Testing RESTful services which is better?

Tags: testing, rest

We have bunch of WebServices to test and am looking for automating them which scripting is better and easy way( with SSL support)

- 1) Groovy - HTTP builder      2)
- 2)Perl -  Which module to use ?
- 3) Python -urllib ?
- 4) SOAPUI - I'm already using this for SOAP/HTTP services and happy with this, however, I
      didn't get WADL file to test REST services.

I'm NOT fully convinced with fiddler,POSTER and Rest-client from google code...

Comment: Have you looked at curl? http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: How useful it would be use CURL ?

Comment: This question should have been posted and should be moved to Software Quality Assurance & Testing

Answer (score 0):

I've found SOAPUI to be marvelously easy to use.  You can incorporate GROOVY scripts as needed if you need to do extra-fancy things (this may be a PRO feature).

SoapUI also supports SSL authentication.

Comment: I know about soapui and am using it for a while for SOAP/HTTP. For RESTful services, I do not have WADL file to use SOAPUI. Hence am asking for alternative.

Comment: I missed that...without the WSDL/WADL - how do you plan on generating requests?  If you already have the requests, you don't need the wsdl/wadl to create a project in SoapUI

Comment: hmm,without WADL file, I will be creating testsuite for my 100's of service methods. Which will be generated automatically,if I have WDAL file.

Answer (score 0):

> 2)Perl - Which module to use ?

Take a look at [swat](https://github.com/melezhik/swat) a DSL for web, rest services test automation, extensible with Perl. Swat is written in Perl as well. Swat uses curl API under the hood and very friendly to start with.

Disclosure - I am the author of swat.